# get the location for objects in a firebase array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have two firebase databases, one that stores post data, and the other stores a number and an email address. The second is so a user can enter a number and is returned the email that is associated with said number. How can I search though an object like that using either angular-fire or jQuery?

Here is the structure for the object I am searching through:

```
{roomNumber : "value", roomEmail  : "email"}
```

I want an input to search through the value "roomNumber" and return the appropriate "roomEmail" only if it matches perfectly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are getting from fire base is an array of objects, then you can achieve this by using javaScript:

```
function search(value){
  var ret = "";
  yourFireBaseArrayObject.forEach(function(obj) {
       if(obj.roomNumber === value){
         ret = obj.roomEmail;  
         return;
       }
   }
   return ret;
 }
```